# Replace NA values depending on specific rules

Tags: r

I am working on a dataset where a score calculated based on data collected from a clinical record. In some cases this data has been  omitted and so the score cannot be calculated and is recorded as NA.

In some cases I am able to substitute an NA value with a previous value. The limitations for this approach are:

If score is NA check whether previous and next values are NA. If both previous and next values are not NA then insert the mean of those scores.

If score is NA check whether previous and next values are NA. IF only previous value is not NA then replace first NA value with previous value.

If there are two or more NA values in sequence only replace the fist NA value leave others as NA.

I have tried the function zoo::na.locf() but this indiscriminately either will replace all NA's or limit to replacing Gaps greated than a number of NAs.

I looked at tidy fill but the documentation didn't include anything about setting limits for filling.

For the following data:

```
ID,episode,score
1,1,1
1,2,1
1,3,1
1,4,NA
1,5,NA
1,6,NA
1,7,2
1,8,NA
1,9,4
1,10,NA
2,1,NA
2,2,2
2,3,3
2,4,4
2,5,NA
2,6,NA
2,7,3
2,8,NA
2,9,NA
2,10,NA
```

So I think that I am on the right track with the below nested ifelse mutate but I'm missing knowledge about functions that I can use to limit my replacement to certain numbers of NA values

```r
data <- data %>%
group_by(ID) %>%
arrange(episode) %>%
mutate(score = ifelse(is.na(score) & lag(!is.na(score)) & lead(!is.na(score)), average(sum(lag(score),lead(score))),
    ifelse(is.na(score) & lag(!is.na(score)) & lead(is.na(score)), lag(score), ...) #And this is where I get stuck as I am unsure how to code for NA runs greater than 1
```

My expected output would be:

```
ID,episode,score
1,1,1
1,2,1
1,3,1
1,4,*1
1,5,NA
1,6,NA
1,7,2
1,8,*3
1,9,4
1,10,*4
2,1,NA
2,2,2
2,3,3
2,4,4
2,5,*4
2,6,NA
2,7,3
2,8,*3
2,9,NA
2,10,NA
```

*s added to make it clear where values are copied.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Computationally speaking, you could reduce your three rules to just one compound condition:

> Replace each `NA` with the mean of its neighbors if `is.na(score[i]) && !is.na(score[i - 1])`, i.e. the element is `NA` and the prior element is not `NA`.

For this to work you simply need to pass `na.rm = T` into `mean()`, i.e. `mean(x[(i-1):(i+1)], na.rm = T)`, which you can use in an `*apply` function, or in `map`, as I've done below. Notice that I've also chosen to reference and assign values by index position, rather than using using `lead` and `lag`, which generate extra vectors. It might be less exciting, but it is also more efficient:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

mutate(df, score = map(seq_along(score),
                       ~ ifelse(
                           is.na(score[.]) && !is.na(score[. - 1]),
                           mean(score[(. - 1):(. + 1)], na.rm = T),
                           score[.]
                       )))

#### OUTPUT ####

   ID episode score
1   1       1     1
2   1       2     1
3   1       3     1
4   1       4     1
5   1       5    NA
6   1       6    NA
7   1       7     2
8   1       8     3
9   1       9     4
10  1      10     4
11  2       1    NA
12  2       2     2
13  2       3     3
14  2       4     4
15  2       5     4
16  2       6    NA
17  2       7     3
18  2       8     3
19  2       9    NA
20  2      10    NA
```

Answer (score 2):

If I understand correctly, there are only two rules for replacing `NA` values in column `score` for each `ID`:

1. If there is a single `NA` value replace it by the mean of the preceeding and succeeding (non-NA) values.
2. If there is a sequence of two or more `NA` values replace only the first `NA` value by the preceeding (non-NA) value and leave the other `NA` values as they are.

Implementation of these two rules boils down to two simple `mutate()` statements:
First, all single `NA` values are replaced according to rule 1 by calling `zoo::na.approx()` with `maxgap = 1L`. So only sequences with more than two `NA` values remain (if any). Finally, each `NA` value is replaced by the preceeding value using `if_else()` and `lag()` in oder to fulfill rule 2.

```
library(dplyr)
data %>% 
  group_by(ID) %>% 
  mutate(new_score = zoo::na.approx(score, x = row_number(), maxgap = 1, na.rm = FALSE)) %>% 
  mutate(new_score = if_else(is.na(new_score), lag(new_score), new_score))
```

> ```
> # A tibble: 20 x 4
> # Groups:   ID [2]
>       ID episode score new_score
>    <dbl>   <dbl> <dbl>     <dbl>
>  1     1       1     1         1
>  2     1       2     1         1
>  3     1       3     1         1
>  4     1       4    NA         1
>  5     1       5    NA        NA
>  6     1       6    NA        NA
>  7     1       7     2         2
>  8     1       8    NA         3
>  9     1       9     4         4
> 10     1      10    NA         4
> 11     2       1    NA        NA
> 12     2       2     2         2
> 13     2       3     3         3
> 14     2       4     4         4
> 15     2       5    NA         4
> 16     2       6    NA        NA
> 17     2       7     3         3
> 18     2       8    NA         3
> 19     2       9    NA        NA
> 20     2      10    NA        NA
> ```

Note that a new column `new_score` is created to allow for a comparison, here.

For replacing `score` use

```
data %>% 
  group_by(ID) %>% 
  mutate(score = zoo::na.approx(score, x = row_number(), maxgap = 1, na.rm = FALSE)) %>% 
  mutate(score = if_else(is.na(score), lag(score), score))
```

#### Data

```
data <- readr::read_csv("ID,episode,score
1,1,1
1,2,1
1,3,1
1,4,NA
1,5,NA
1,6,NA
1,7,2
1,8,NA
1,9,4
1,10,NA
2,1,NA
2,2,2
2,3,3
2,4,4
2,5,NA
2,6,NA
2,7,3
2,8,NA
2,9,NA
2,10,NA")
```

Answer (score 1):

An option would be

```
library(dplyr)
data %>%
   group_by(ID) %>% 
  group_by(grp = cumsum(lead(is.na(score) & !is.na(lead(score) & 
      !is.na(lag(score)) ))), add = TRUE) %>% 
  mutate(score1 = if(n() == 3 & is.na(score[2]) & sum(is.na(score))== 1) 
    replace(score, is.na(score), mean(score, na.rm = TRUE)) else score) %>% 
  ungroup %>% 
  select(-grp) %>%
  mutate(score1 = coalesce(score1, lag(score1)))
# A tibble: 20 x 4
#      ID episode score score1
#   <int>   <int> <int>  <dbl>
# 1     1       1     1      1
# 2     1       2     1      1
# 3     1       3     1      1
# 4     1       4    NA      1
# 5     1       5    NA     NA
# 6     1       6    NA     NA
# 7     1       7     2      2
# 8     1       8    NA      3
# 9     1       9     4      4
#10     1      10    NA      4
#11     2       1    NA     NA
#12     2       2     2      2
#13     2       3     3      3
#14     2       4     4      4
#15     2       5    NA      4
#16     2       6    NA     NA
#17     2       7     3      3
#18     2       8    NA      3
#19     2       9    NA     NA
#20     2      10    NA     NA
```